# Could not add nuget package to class library

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017, I created an empty .NET Core Class Library, I tried to add [a package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/amzinet/) to my project and got the following error

> Invalid portable frameworks for '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0'. A portable framework must have at least one framework in the profile

I searched internet for help, could not find anything. This class library is referenced in a `ASP.NET MVC Core` app which does not have a project.json file, I guess [it is gone now](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin How to fix the issue I am having? I want to add a Nuget package but getting an error that is mentioned in the question

Comment: You should probably update your question to mention that you are using C++.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have created a nuget package that you want to use in your projects. Mentioned nuget package is created as `Portable Class Library` and can be installed in regular `Class Library` projects.

If you want to be able to install this package to `.NET Core` class libraries or console apps (which includes web applications) you need to create it as `.NET Standard Class Library`. There is a walk through on how to do it: [Create .NET standard packages with Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017).

**UPDATE:**

From what I have found C++ is not supported in .NET Core and there is no plans to support it right now [Proposal: C++/CX support](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/254), [Will CoreCLR support C++/CLI crossplat?](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/659), [Using .Net (C++/CLI) legacy code in Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10124).

I am not an expert in C++, but maybe it is possible to create a library in C++ and P/Invoke it with C# and wrap both in NuGet package? Or rewrite it completely in C#?

Comment: This walkthrough applies to C# Class Library. My Nuget package contains a class library written in Managed C++, How can I target a Managed C++ project to netstandard1.1?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I don't think there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a workaround for it. Thank you for looking into this for me. Here is the 100